# How to create a VM that mirrors the RoR production version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, virtual-machine, unicorn

I am working on an open source project and there is an issue where an upload error only seems to occur on the production side that is running apache and unicorn. 
 
Due to privacy issues and risks, I am unable to mess around in the actual production side (such as creating a temp id for myself with various privileges.

Is there anyway that I can quickly create a VM with such setup in my own computer that would mirror the live site?

The site is running in RoR 4, latest unicorn, and latest stable version of apache.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you can be able to accomplish this. You can use vagrant and also with the rising popularity of Docker containers, you can easily model production environment on your computer. Since you indicated a faster way to get the VM up and running, I would recommend using [railsbox.io](http://railsbox.io). Its amazing and it saves you a lot of time. According to their webiste -

> Fast and easy Ruby on Rails virtual machines. Streamline your
>   development workflow in no time by creating production-like virtual
>   machine with your development environment. Try this extremely simple
>   to use VM configuration tool to create new Ruby on Rails server using
>   vagrant and ansible.

The app helps you setup a VM with ease.

Comment: I'll try it today and give you the checkmark, but thanks for the suggestions!!

Comment: The railsbox.io is a good suggestion but it doesnt have the apache2 support that I need. Is there a quick docker setup or any other out of the box vms that you are aware of?